# How can I get the result of a formula (text) as part of another bigger formula?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to get a range of cells with Vlookup inside of another lookup. I have written in the cells ranges like `A3:G9` so when vlookup matches it places it in the bigger formula. But it is displayed as `"A3:G9"` (notice the quotation) so it is being obtained as text.

The reason I'm doing this is because inside a lookup I need to match a name to get a range of cells. I'm doing a time table with a list where I can select the name and the related information of the person changes, but I need also to make the whole sheet time to change too. For this I have tables (ranges) with Monday, Tuesday... and 4 different times, coming and leaving in the morning and evening, as well as the amount of hours and if the day is holiday or not.

I have everything ready, but I need just to be able to change the range depending on the name. 
The cell displaying a single hour (i.e. August 1st, Monday) looks like this at the moment:

`=IF(MOD($05;2)=0;VLOOKUP($B5;Horarios!$A$3:$G$9;4;FALSE);VLOOKUP($B5;Horarios!$A$12:$G$18;4;FALSE))`
(Every week the shift changes, so I'm counting odd or even weeks).

In the above code, I don't know what to do in order to change `Horarios!$A$3:$G$9` to another range, so I can take a different table for different working shifts.
`$B5` is the day of the week. Not every day is the same.

So basically, for this cell I need to change the time displayed depending on what worker is selected in the dropdown list and depending also of the day of the week.

I  have tried to put ranges manually as part of a single Vlookup.

`=IF(MOD($O5;2)=0;VLOOKUP($B5;VLOOKUP(C3;U2:AA9;7;FALSE);2;FALSE);VLOOKUP($B5;Horarios!$A$12:$G$18;2;FALSE))`

But in steps to reproduce the formula it shows as `=IF(MOD($O5;2)=0;VLOOKUP($B5;"A3:G9";2;FALSE);VLOOKUP($B5;Horarios!$A$12:$G$18;2;FALSE))`

Edit: Pictures.
[TimeTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzeqQ.jpg)
[Origin of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDa2k.jpg)

here you can see, If i change the month, the cells change the time as not every week is the same. I would like to apply a time table depending on the worker above too. In the second picture you can see the time tables, 2 by person (1 per week, it is a 15 days shift).

Comment: Can you mock up a few lines and [edit] your question to show that mock data.  It would help us understand what you want.

Comment: Check [INDIRECT FUNCTION](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). It references a specific range , where name of that range is a string. To make it easy, if you type `=SUM(INDIRECT("B1:B10")` would be the same that typing `SUM(B1:B10)` but as you know, strings can be changed with other formulas :). INDIRECT is what you need for sure.

Comment: Please, do not post images in comments. Edit your original question and add this new info.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I don't think this is the solution. This still gets the value of a cell as text.

Comment: So `VLOOKUP(C3;U2:AA9;7;FALSE)` returns `A3:G9` as text? IF yes, try `=IF(MOD($O5;2)=0;VLOOKUP($B5;INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(C3;U2:AA9;7;FALSE));2;FALSE);VLOOKUP($B5;Horarios!$A$12:$G$18;2;FALSE))`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes, indirect worked. The explanation in the documentation wasn't clear enough for me, but this works perfectly. Thank  you very much for your help!

Comment: Nice, I'll post it as an answer then you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, just needed a little help with INDIRECT:

> **[INDIRECT Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)**

With this function, you can easily get a reference to a range specified with a text string.

In your case, a part of your formula, `VLOOKUP(C3;U2:AA9;7;FALSE)` returns a range address as text, `A3:G9`. So with that string inside INDIRECT can be *converted* to a range and work with it as a range.

`=IF(MOD($O5;2)=0;VLOOKUP($B5;INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(C3;U2:AA9;7;FALSE));2;FALSE);VLOOKUP($B5;Horarios!$A$12:$G$18;2;FALSE))` will make the work for you :)